# Python packaging semantic versioning >= vs. ~= in requirements.txt

Tags: python, package, semantic-versioning, requirements.txt

I have a general question about handling versions in `requirements.txt` of my package `foo`. I cannot decide if `>=` or `~=` is better.

- assume `pandas~=1.3.3` in `requirements.txt` of my package `foo`

  - in this case, I can guarantee that tests and code of `foo` works correctly for `pandas` patches
  - **problem**: if there is a minor (or even major) change to `1.4.0` in `pandas`, a third package cannot use `foo` anymore with `pandas==1.4.0`. So I have to release `foo` again with `pandas~=1.4.0`. This means that I have to release constantly ...
- assume `pandas>=1.3.3` in my `requirements.txt` of my package `foo`

  - I thought the `>=` could solve the problem. With `>=`, `foo` can still be used. But ...
  - **problem**: this means that `foo` can even be used with major changes like `pandas==2.1.1`. I do not know if `foo` still works correctly. Probably the tests even fail but I won't notice ...

I am confused and I do not know what to do.

What is best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: If pandas `1.3.0` version is also compatible, versioning with `~=1.3` will accept any `1.x` version that is at least `1.3`, but will not accept new major releases.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. This is an option as minor upgrades should be fine as well. But as you said, the problem with major releases still exist.

Comment: But you said you don't want versions like `2.1.1` accepted. `~=1.3` will not accept such version.

Comment: hmmm, okay, you are right. But then it seems that this is the solution. Just write ~=1.3. If there is a pandas major release, I obviously have to adjust my package but this is okay as anything can happen in a major release. So general question: is that best practice?